# Multiple versions of a project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a  product with a few clients. Currently this product is the same for all of them in terms of look and functionality.I need to implement a few new features called the beta features and make them available to only a few of my clients, rest of the clients will be using the older version and their maintenance requests will be done too. I don't want to duplicate the entire solution for this. What is the best approach for this problem ?. Is maintaining solution with `visual studio configuration manager` and `#if`   the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If beta-features are planned to roll out finally to all customers this sounds like version control branching issue.  With modern Version Control System like Git you can create beta [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) to handle different development paths.

While your master development branch goes on during maintenance, you can make feature branches where you implement beta-features to certain customers and finally merge them to master branch.

If you try handle this issue in single branch by `#iffing` your source-code, you have chosen complex path which is error-prone and difficult to scale up.